# How did Swarm integrate Facebook Messenger?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk, messenger

Our app requires Facebook to sign-up. Our most requested feature after our beta was messaging, and we noticed Swarm has a built-in button for instant Facebook Message that is essentially a pointer to a new message to said person in the Messenger app. We can't seem to locate any documentation on the feature in the Facebook SDK. Does anybody have a clue how they pulled it off? It would save us from a lot of development time if we could do the same!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1Rq2.png

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to the Message dialog?

If so, it's pretty easy to implement via the Facebook  iOS SDK, and involves triggering 
`FBDialogs presentMessageDialogWithLink` or one of the related methods (e.g. photos use a specific method, `presentMessageDialogWithPhotos`) - there's also a corresponding `canPresentMessageDialogWithParams` method to determine if triggering the dialog would work

Explanation and examples: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/share#message-dialog

Reference docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBDialogs/

For Android it's pretty similar and uses `FacebookDialog.MessageDialogBuilder`, docs are here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share#message-dialog

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however, I'm aware of these options. None of the message dialogs from the SDK offer a way to programmatically select which friend or friends the message dialog opens to. If you download Swarm you'll have a better understanding of what I'm trying to do.